# Different 2D projections of a 3D knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

[Somewhat relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_from_Projections)

Just curious: Obviously two projections of an embedding $S^1 \to \Bbb R^3$ can differ by a Reidemeister move. Or more of them. But when can two diagrams for the same knot (or link) **type** be projections of one common knot (or link), i.e. we are asking to realize two distinct diagrams as projections of one common embedding $S^1 \to \Bbb R^3$, simultaneously.

For example: Take $L8a5=8^2_{11}$. We can "flype" one crossing into either strand (KnotAtlas: from blue to green), giving two projections that are equivalent, but nontrivially different. (Different Gauss code, right?) Can a 3D model of $L8a5$ look like these two projections from different angles?

Comment: I can't make sense of your question.  Your 3rd sentence is asking when a projection of a "knot or link" is an "actual projection" of a 3d object.  A knot or link isn't a 3d object?  What does "3D object" mean?

Comment: Maybe what's being asked is, when can two equivalent knot diagrams both be physical projections of the same three-dimensional realization of the knot?

Comment: Okay, so given an embedding $f : S^1 \to \Bbb R^3$  for $v \in S^2$ there are orthogonal projection maps $\pi_v : \Bbb R^3 \to v^\perp$.  The set $\pi_v(f(S^1))$ is a diagram in the orthogonal complement $v^\perp$ (a proper knot diagram if you keep track of crossing data).  For a generic $f$ there are only finitely many of these diagrams, up to diffeomorphism of the planes.   So the question is, how many of these diagrams can you realize simultaneously, as projections of a common knot?  i.e. is it possible that two diagrams of a knot can't be realized simultaneously?

Comment: This is assuming your question "But when can two given projections of the same knot or link be actual projections of a 3D object?" should be written as "When can two projections from a knot isotopy class be projections of one knot (from different directions)?"

Comment: Certainly you can't realize any two projections of the unknot simultaneously: for example the round projection allows for only a very restricted class of other projections, where the crossings (using the knot ordering) are all overcrossings, then all undercrossings, before repeating.

Comment: Your question is a little like asking how many diagrams of a knot type are realizable via polynomials of degree $n$.  The polynomial degree restricts the diagrams greatly, much like how one projection forces restrictions on any other.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Your interpretation is correct, it's just that I'm an amateur and can't formulate mathematically watertight! Feel free to edit the question, maybe like Gerry formulated it ;-)

Comment: I suspect that there are examples of projections of a realization of the unknot that cannot have another projection without any crossings. If an unknot has a crossingless projection, then it bounds an disk in its convex hull. Whereas there are examples of unknots that don’t bound a disk in their convex hull. One would have to prove that this property held for any 3D unknot that has a particular projection. The examples in this paper ought to work. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-002-2707-6 See also https://doi.org/10.2307/1970922